# Unity webgl html5 custom microsoft power bi visual

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, typescript, powerbi

I'm building a custom visual for power bi that needs to generate a 3D model. I'm trying to integrate the Unity html5 web-gl player, but cannot figure out how to include external non-typeScript files when building with the visual with powerbi-cli. Is it possible to run javascript files in power bi?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add JavaScript libraries of your choice to Power BI.

You just need to copy the files into the custom visual project and add the reference to your `tsconfig.json` file under `"files"`.

Details: [Adding External Libraries](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/Tutorial/ExternalLibraries.md)